# General solution for $f(n)$ satisfying $(x^n+y^n)^2=[x^2+y^2-2xyf(n)]^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm have being studying the following equation for a while;
$$(x^n+y^n)^2=[x^2+y^2-2xyf(n)]^n$$
what makes this equation interesting for me is that at $n=2$ the equation can be satisfied if $f(n)=0$. And at $n=1$, the equation can be satisfied again if $f(n)=-1$ (notice the solutions for $f$ are indvidual from values of $x$ and $y$). So i was wondering what value $f(n)$ should take when $n=3$ and so on. My goal is to find a solution that is independent of the value of $x$ and $y$.

I tried to solve this equation by defining the function $A(x,y,n)=(x^n+y^n)^2-[x^2+y^2-2xyf(n)]^n$, then for correct value of $f(n)$ volume under curve should be $0$; and hence solving for $f(n)$;

$$\iint^{∞}_{-∞}A(x,y.n)dV=0$$

however this method didn't work because the integral didn't converge. I also tried to take derivatives to cancelout all the variables, but the method didn't give any useful results as well. Can someone help me please, this problem has being in my head for so long time i couldn't think of any method to solve it anymore. Thank you guys and thanks for such great platform!.

Comment: Why do you believe that such a function exists?  If we take $x=y$ we get $2^2x^{2n}=2^nx^{2n}(1-f(n))^n$ which lets you solve for $f(n)$.  But I see no reason to imagine that this $f(n)$ will work for any other pairs $(x,y)$.  Should be easy to check.

Comment: What I suggest:  solve for $f(n)$ under the assumption that $x=y$.  Then solve for it under the assumption that $x=2y$.  Do you get the same result?  If not, there is no such function.  I'd start with $n=3$, of course.

Comment: i don't have a proof that such solution don't exist. Meanwhile I hope there is such a solution even if its complex @lulu

Comment: I showed you how to prove that no such function exists. Just take $n=3$ and follow the steps I wrote.